# How Do I GET Number Range with a SPACE From A PHP String?

Tags: php, laravel, preg-match

I have table values like this.

Boys - Age 0 - 1

Women

Boys - Age 1 - 2

Boys - Age 1

Boys - Age 2

Girls - Age 3 - 4

Boys - Age 1

Boys - Age 2

Original array:

```
    [ 0 => "Boys - Age 0 - 1" 1 => "Women" 2 => "Boys - Age 0 - 1" 
3 => "Boys - Age 1" 4 => "Boys - Age 2" 5 => "Boys - Age 3" 
6 => "Boys - Age 4" 7 => "Boys - Age 5" 8 => "Boys - Age 6" 
9 => "Boys - Age 7" 10 => "Boys - Age 8" 11 => "Boys - Age 9" ]
```

now I want to get the only size from these values I have tried explode but it gives me size in the 3rd index and sometimes 2nd index that's not acceptable.

OUTPUT I need like this by foreach loop.
0 - 1

women

1 - 2

1

2

3 - 4

1

2

Sample Data[image]

Comment: Do you have array with original value?

Comment: yes, can I give you here?

Comment: [ 0 => "Boys - Age 0 - 1"
    1 => "Women"
    2 => "Boys - Age 0 - 1"
    3 => "Boys - Age 1"
    4 => "Boys - Age 2"
    5 => "Boys - Age 3"
    6 => "Boys - Age 4"
    7 => "Boys - Age 5"
    8 => "Boys - Age 6"
    9 => "Boys - Age 7"
    10 => "Boys - Age 8"
    11 => "Boys - Age 9"
   
  ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

**Code:**

```
<?php

$arr = array( 0 => "Boys - Age 0 - 1", 1 => "Women", 2 => "Boys - Age 0 - 1", 3 => "Boys - Age 1", 4 => "Boys - Age 2", 5 => "Boys - Age 3", 6 => "Boys - Age 4", 7 => "Boys - Age 5", 8 => "Boys - Age 6", 9 => "Boys - Age 7", 10 => "Boys - Age 8", 11 => "Boys - Age 9" );

foreach($arr as $row) {
    $array = explode('-', $row, 2);
    if($array[1] != '')
        $finalArr[] = trim(str_replace('Age ','',$array[1]));
}

print_r($finalArr);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0 - 1
    [1] => 0 - 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 4
    [6] => 5
    [7] => 6
    [8] => 7
    [9] => 8
    [10] => 9
)
```

**Demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/836649)**

Comment: above answer by Prasad but its little but cmplex logic 0 => "0 - 1"

The output of your code is like this  0 => " 0 - 1"

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
foreach ($data as $val) {
    $splitVal = explode('-', $val);
  if (isset($splitVal[1])) {
    $finalResult[] = filter_var($splitVal[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT).(isset($splitVal[2])?'-'.$splitVal[2]:'');
    }    
}
```

Comment: i am going to mark your answer acceptable but i need to understand whats going on can you please explain little bit more.?

Comment: @MuhammadAmirShahzad, Its explode data array with "-" and filter it with integer and only appends if second index of array value exists.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match('/\d(\s-\s\d)?/', $val, $matches)) {
        echo $matches[0].'<br>'; // Or whatever you want to make with that result
    }
}
```

This code retrieves the part of the string that is comprised of a digit, eventually followed by an hyphen and another digit, and prints it. That line can be replaced to put it in an array instead, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the value:

```
$array = array( 0 => "Boys - Age 0 - 1", 1 => "Women", 2 => "Boys - Age 0 - 1", 3 => "Boys - Age 1", 4 => "Boys - Age 2", 5 => "Boys - Age 3", 6 => "Boys - Age 4" ,7 => "Boys - Age 5" ,8 => "Boys - Age 6", 9 => "Boys - Age 7", 10 => "Boys - Age 8", 11 => "Boys - Age 9" ) ;

foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
$value_number=explode('Boys - Age',$value);
if (isset($value_number[1]))
    echo $value_number[1]."\n";
}
$value_number=explode('Girls - Age',$value);
if (isset($value_number[1]))
    echo $value_number[1]."\n";
}
$value_number=explode('Kids - Age',$value);
if (isset($value_number[1]))
    echo $value_number[1]."\n";
}
```

Comment: Its not fix all the time `'Boys - Age'`. Check edited question of him